# CSS: position image on bottom right corner

Tags: html, css

I've this image, that I need to position in the bottom right corner of the div.

I've tried using margin-right and padding-right 0px on the img tag but this does not work.

***Blacklines means I don't need that space***

[image]

Here is a CodePen:

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/OrZKOr

```
<header class="header" id="header1">
    <img class="margin_right_zero" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alphadsy/alpha-ui/master/images/man.png" width="440px" height="320px">
    <div class="circle">
        <div class="caption">
            <h2 class="title display-3">Alphad <strong>Design & Inpsertion</strong></h2>
            <p>Lorem m nisi! Eum vitae ipsam veniam, ullam explicabo quaerat asperiores veritatis nam reprehenderit necessitatibus sequi.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**Update 1**:

Most answers solve bottom margin, but not right margin.

**You have to open the CodePen in Full Page to see this detail.**

[image]

Comment: Currently your image has `left: 50%`, instead of that, use `right: 0; bottom: 0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that with this:

```
#header1 img {
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Note the -10px, is to offset the white space in the image.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PXeMgv

Comment: Please, see UPDATE 1.

Comment: Hi @OmarGonzales can you please send your code pen? The one I linked, I do not see your issue from Update 1. Or which browser are you using?

Comment: Just used your codepen link, forked and view it in full page:

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/full/QzxLOd

Comment: There is a little gap in the right bottom corner, that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @OmarGonzales fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily made with `absolute` positioning in css.
Just add this on your css

```
.bottom_right{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

And add change the class on your image to `bottom_right`

Remember that the container of every "absoluted" element needs to has its position to `relative` 
So, add this to your css to ensure the image never leaves its container

```
header{ position:relative; }
```

Here is your CodePen updated:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JwvgzM

Comment: Ty. But this solves bottom part, not right part. Please, see update 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your image uses `position: absolute;`. The image's position is primarily defined by `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`. Since you've already included `left: 50%` it won't 'listen' to your margin and padding settings.

Setting the following will set your image to the bottom right:

```
#header1 img {
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

or move the image to the end at the HTML code, this simplifies the job :-)

```
<header class="header" id="header1">
    <div class="circle">
        <div class="caption">
            <h2 class="title display-3">Alphad <strong>Design & Inpsertion</strong></h2>
            <p>Lorem m nisi! Eum vitae ipsam veniam, ullam explicabo quaerat asperiores veritatis nam reprehenderit necessitatibus sequi.</p>
        </div>
        <img class="margin_right_zero" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alphadsy/alpha-ui/master/images/man.png" width="440px" height="320px">
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```css
.bottomright {
  top: unset;
  left: unset;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in full screen:

```css
.margin_right_zero { 
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 24%;
}
```

I think that all you need after that is to adjust the % value for responsiveness if you want the picture to appear on tablet or mobile.